# my eslint-plugin-react-hooks doesn't work

Tags: eslint, cra, airbnb-js-styleguide

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ['airbnb', 'prettier', 'eslint:recommended', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],

  // prettier/react 추가
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    sourceType: 'module',
    allowImportExportEverywhere: true,
  },
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
    'import/no-unresolved': 0,
    'prettier/prettier': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'react/destructuring-assignment': 'warn',
  },
};
```

here is my .esLintrc.
After applying airbnb eslint this time, the 'react/destruction-assignment' warning doesn't work.
Is there any problem with my .esLintrc.file?

I touched my .esLintrc settings a little, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The rule value you are using is wrong, thats why its not working.

The rule can be set to either of `always` or `never` like:

```
"react/destructuring-assignment": [<enabled>, 'always']
```

You can also see this [link](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md) for reference of this rule.